# Vuetify v-footer overlays content

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, footer

I'm having troubles with v-footer. It overlays the content. I see this happens when I include images. Look this pen:

https://codepen.io/slayerbleast/pen/zYxYXZL

if you go scrolling to the end you will see how the footer grows at the end overlaping the content
why do that? I only want the footer creates his own space...
And this effect is worse for small devices, just resize the window

This is the layout:

```html
<v-app>
  <div class="header">
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title class="title">
            {{ user.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <template v-slot:append>
        <v-list-item link @click="logout">
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>logout</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              logout
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar absolute app dark height="100" class="px-12">
      (...)
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>

  <v-content>
    <p>content</p>
  </v-content>

  <v-footer absolute inset app width="auto" class="py-12">
    <v-container>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col lg="2" md="3" cols="12" align-self="center">
          <v-img
            src="https://picsum.photos/id/419/200/300"
            max-width="50"
            max-height="50"
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added `heigth="200"` to the v-footer:

```html
<v-footer absolute inset app height="200" width="auto" class="py-12">
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col lg="2" md="3" cols="12" align-self="center">
        <v-img
          src="https://picsum.photos/id/419/200/300"
          max-width="50"
          max-height="50"
        />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-footer>
```

https://codepen.io/TheEvilThinker/pen/JjooLmM

Comment: What if I need to have a dynamic height? On a desktop device the footer will be about 150px but on a mobile device converting columns into rows the footer will grow to about 350px.... how can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `absolute` and `app` props...

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      ...
    </v-content>
    <v-footer inset width="auto" class="py-12">
      <v-container>
        <v-row justify="center">
          <v-col lg="2" md="3" cols="12" align-self="center">
            <v-img
              src="https://picsum.photos/id/419/200/300"
              max-width="50"
              max-height="50"
            />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/1BmDspkD9n

Comment: I need these props because I have a navigation drawer fixed on the left... If I remove app prop the footer goes on the background of the navigation drawer...

Comment: app props is for Vuetify layout: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/